# infobox to pushpin via geocode, close all open infoboxs before opening new infobox

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

ok, here is my code

```
    const members = [
                {name: 'Abc Ijk',   order: '646545', duration: '1.20h', createdOn: '02/03/2021 09:00 - 10:00', address: '1221 test Avenue Room 112 Portland OR 97204' },
                {name: 'Xyz Opq',   order: '646546', duration: '3.00h', createdOn: '02/03/2021 08:00 - 11:00', address: '945 nw street 852 Portland OR 97209' }
    ];

        function loadEmpStatus() {
            // var navigationBarMode = Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode;
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('sdy-fserv-map'), {
                /* No need to set credentials if already passed in URL */
                // navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode.compact,
                // supportedMapTypes: [Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial, Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.grayscale, Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.canvasLight],
                supportedMapTypes: [Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial],
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.624527, -122.355255),
                maxZoom: 11,
                minZoom: 5
            });

            for( let row of members ) {
                console.log(row);
                doGeocode( map, row );
            }
        }

        function doGeocode( map, data ) {
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                var searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                var requestOptions = {
                    bounds: map.getBounds(),
                    where: data.address,
                    callback: function (answer, userData) {
                        map.setView({ bounds: answer.results[0].bestView });
                        var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(answer.results[0].location, {
                            icon: 'https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Content/images/poi_custom.png',
                        });
                        // map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(answer.results[0].location));
                        map.entities.push(pushpin);

                        var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(answer.results[0].location, {
                            title: data.name,
                            description: data.address, visible: false,
                            actions: [
                                { label: 'Handler1', eventHandler: function () { console.log('Handler1'); } },
                                { label: 'Handler2', eventHandler: function () { console.log('Handler2'); } },
                            ]
                        });
                        infobox.setMap(map);
                        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', function () {
                            infobox.setOptions({ visible: true });
                        });
                        map.entities.push(pushpin);/**/
                    }
                };
                searchManager.geocode(requestOptions);
            });
        }
```

it runs smoothly and I have geocoded pushpins with infoboxes attached and showing up nicely.

[image]

But I am failing to figure out how to make all opened infoboxes close before opening new infobox on pushpin click event.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend creating a single infobox and reusing it as outline in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/infoboxes/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes

Comment: yes, I agree! yet my only issue is, in this example data is coming from the {TestDataGenerator.getLocations} while I have addresses which I have to resolve before I render and this is why I have multiple infoboxes!

Comment: That is a minor difference. If anything this would make things easier. Create the main infobox first and hide it, then load your addresses as pins like previously. To make things a bit easier, consider using a layer and adding a single event to that rather than using the legacy `map.entities.push` method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/layers/data-layer-events